# Hibernate throws "NULL not allowed for column" as the JPA OneToOne relation FK is missing in the SQL INSERT when using @MapsId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

On my OneToOne relation I am getting: 
`NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into customer_order (id, enabled, orden_id) values (null, ?, ?)`.

It is actually `null` because is not present in the `INSERT` query. However, the value `USER` is filled in `customerOder` entity when perfom `save(customerOrder)`.

```java
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    @Default
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'true'", nullable = false)
    private Boolean enabled = Boolean.TRUE;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_order")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class CustomerOrderEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("id")
    private UserEntity user;

       //other values
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class UserEntity extends AbstractEntity {

    @NaturalId
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(length = 28, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String uuid;

//other values
}
```

I expect the `customerOrder` to be persisted in database with the filled data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`@MapsId`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) allows you to use the child table Primary Key as a Foreign Key to the parent table Primary Key.

If you enable the `hbm2ddl` tool, you will see that the `customer_order` table will not contain the `user_id` column.

However, since you generated the database schema previously and you have a `customer_order` table with a dedicated `user_id` column, then you need to remove `@MapsId`:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private UserEntity user;
```

This way, the `user` association will use the `user_id` Foreign Key column.

Comment: Removing `@MapsId("id")` annotation solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works exactly as you specified.

If you have a shared key (you use @MapsId), Hibernate won’t use a separate column for the foreign key. This is why the insert query does not contain `user_id` column.

On top if that, id in CustomerOrderEntity is on one hand auto-generated (as defined in the superclass), and on the other maps id of another entity. These are conflicting requirements.